# Is there a way to remove chart border using Google sheet script

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, charts

I'm trying to draw some graphs using google sheet app script, and I need to remove the chart border. below code is I am using now,

```
     function drwcolchrt(sh,rng){
      var ttl = rng.getValues()[0][0]
      var chart = sh.newChart()
      .asColumnChart()
      .setColors(["#b6d7a8"])
      .addRange(rng)
      .setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_COLUMNS)
      .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(false)
      .setNumHeaders(1)
      .setHiddenDimensionStrategy(Charts.ChartHiddenDimensionStrategy.IGNORE_BOTH)
      .setOption('reverseCategories', true)
      .setOption('applyAggregateData', 0)

      .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true)
      .setOption('isStacked', 'false')
      .setOption('title', ttl)

     .setOption('series.0.aggregateFunction', 'count')
     .setOption('height', 255)
     .setOption('width', 413)
     .setPosition(3, 5, 1, 3)

     .build();
     sh.insertChart(chart);

     }
```

Can somebody help me? and also I need to draw x-axis on ascending order.

Comment: Can't you just override the chart's CSS to hide the border?

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, can't we just change it from .setOptions() ?? I don't what is the option that refers to Chart border.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the border you are trying to remove?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68607665/changing-a-chart-border-color-in-google-apps-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try adding:

`setOption('backgroundColor', {'stroke':'#666', 'strokeWidth':0, 'fill': 'white'})`

---

**References:**

You can get a lot of configuration options for any chart by going to Guides > Chart Types and for each chart there is its particular options.

[combo chart options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart#configuration-options)

Comment: Tried this. Although the fill color is used, the stroke and strokeWidth values seem to be ignored. Other ideas?

Comment: Seems to be a bug that is currently marked as "won't fix". See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150189790