# Changing a Chart Border Color in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts

I'm working in Google Apps Script, and I'm inserting a chart into my sheet through a script. I noticed when recording the creation of the chart with a macro, not all of the attributes of the chart get recorded.

For example, I record a macro and I set the background of the chart to be transparent (or any color really), then when I run that macro, the background comes back a standard white.

I am able to fix the background color by setting it in under `.setOptions` (see code  below), but I can't seem to figure out how to change the color of a border (really I want to just get rid of it).

```
  chart = sheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1").newChart()
    .asLineChart()
    .addRange(sheet.getSheetByName("ForGraphs").getRange(1, 1, 22, team_names.length + 1))
    .setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_COLUMNS)
    .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(false)
    .setNumHeaders(-1)
    .setHiddenDimensionStrategy(Charts.ChartHiddenDimensionStrategy.IGNORE_BOTH)
    .setOption('backgroundColor.fill', "#0000ffff")
    .setOption('bubble.stroke', '#000000')
    .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true)
    .setOption('focusTarget', 'category')
    .setOption('curveType', 'none')
    .setOption('legend.position', 'top')
    .setOption('annotations.domain.textStyle.color', '#808080')
    .setOption('textStyle.color', '#000000')
    .setOption('legend.textStyle.color', '#1a1a1a')
    .setOption('subtitleTextStyle.color', '#999999')
    .setOption('titleTextStyle.color', '#757575')
    .setOption('annotations.total.textStyle.color', '#808080')
    .setOption('hAxis.slantedText', true)
    .setOption('hAxis.slantedTextAngle', 0)
    .setOption('hAxis.textStyle.color', '#000000')
    .setOption('hAxis.titleTextStyle.color', '#000000')
    .setOption('vAxes.0.minorGridlines.count', 5)
    .setOption('vAxes.0.minorGridlines.color', '#f3f3f3')
    .setOption('vAxes.0.textStyle.color', '#000000')
    .setOption('vAxes.0.titleTextStyle.color', '#000000')
    .setOption('height', 322)
    .setOption('width', 659)
    .setPosition(26, 5, 2, 16)
    .build();
```

I've manually added the `.setOption('backgroundColor', "#0000ffff")` into this chunk.

I see in Google's [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/chart-configuration-options#line-chart-configuration-options) that they say the `backgroundColor.fill` option can take an object as an input, but they neglect to say what they object will look like. I would assume it would be something with a `.stroke` and `.strokeWeight`, but that hasn't seemed to work.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means you can set by either `setOption('backgroundcolor', 'white')` or `setOption('backgroundcolor', {fill:'white'})`

According to the document, not further option for background is supported

---

Line colors are set by `setOptions('colors', ['blue', 'red'])`

---

Chart area background color is set by `chartArea.backgroundColor`

It is stated in the document.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful to understand how the documentation reads. But I'm still wondering if there's a way to change the border of a chart.

Comment: It seems I have confused with Line color. Answer updated.

Comment: I can't see a way to change the border using this either.  I was able to use `.setOption('backgroundColor', { fill: '#ffffff', stroke: '#ffffff', strokeWidth: -1 })` and the fill color was used but various stroke values (suggested by the documentation) seemed to be ignored. Note also that this needs to be done early in the object creation – making it the first `setOption()` seemed to work best. Side note: the function `.setBackgroundColor()` will also set the color, but also only if used early in the object creation chain.

Comment: Seems to be a bug that (as of writing) has been marked as won't fix: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150189790